# Prove that the function $f:[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]\to R, f(x)=x-\cos x$ is bijective

Tags: functions, trigonometry, inverse

> Prove that the following function is bijective and calculate its inverse
>
> $$f : [0, \frac{\pi}{2}] \to \mathbb R, \qquad f(x)= x - \cos (x)$$

Proved it's injective (increasing on $2k\pi < x < \frac{3\pi}{2}+2k\pi$, where k is a constant in Z, which is included in $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ ) but I'm not sure to prove it's surjective

I calculated the limits for $-\infty$ and $\infty$ but the results aren't in the co-domain. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something but don't know what. Any ideas ?

Comment: It is not surjective. $f(x)= x-\cos{x}$ can not exceed $1+\frac{\pi}{2}$ on $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Comment: So the co-domain is wrong ? I assume it's bijective on R (according to wolframalpha)

Comment: But if you want to study $g\colon [0, \frac{\pi}{2}] \to [-1, \frac{\pi}{2}]$, $g(x) = x - \cos{x}$ instead ...

Comment: Likely the problem wants you to show that it is bijective with its image.  Occasionally, I've seen this type of language in older books.